# GetCustomAttribute<> extension method returns null?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I'm trying to use the GetCustomAttribute<> extension method in my application is it returning always null. Also, tried with the Attribute.GetCustomAttribute() and having the same issue. Below is the main program and attribute definition in the class library (.net framework 4.7.2) and would like to know what is causing the issue. Appreciate any solution for this issue.

Main program:

```
        var classtype = typeof(AssemblyAttribute);
        //Get Assembly information from Class type
        var assembly = classtype.Assembly;

        // Load assembly
        var asmFromFile = Assembly.LoadFile(assembly.Location);

        // Get custom attribute using extension m  - Option 1
        var attr = asmFromFile.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyAttribute>();

        // Get custom attribute - Option 2

        var ca  = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(assembly, typeof(AssemblyAttribute));
```

### AssemblyAttribute.cs (AssemblyAttribute.dll)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class AssemblyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }

    public AssemblyAttribute(string moduleName)
    {
        ModuleName = moduleName;
    }
}
```

Tried multiple options for loading the class library and different methods (extension method and method from System.Attribute class) and having issues with all these scenarios.

Comment: Have you actually *applied* the attribute anywhere, using `[assembly: Assembly(ModuleName = ...)]`? That part of the code seems to be missing. Retrieving the attribute type is not the same thing as retrieving an attribute instance.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre]  guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to add missing details - in particular "the other assembly" where the attribute should be used as @JeroenMostert pointing out.